# UWP resource strings at design time (.resw)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I've created a .resw file by following the instructions at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/put-ui-strings-into-resources. While the localization works fine at runtime, no text is displayed at design time.

The only solution proposed so far seems to only work in windows 8.1 apps: [Windows store app ResourceLoader at design time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004634/windows-store-app-resourceloader-at-design-time)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `New Method` of solution that you have mentioned also works in UWP. And it's more recommended to use [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth) at design time.

The following class works like .resw file `reader`. If you send the key parameter it will return the value for key.

```
public class LocalizedStrings
{
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            return ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse().GetString(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Before using binding, you need to instantiate the `reader` in the App.xaml file.

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:LocalizedStrings x:Key="Localized"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**Resources.resw**

```
<data name="Title" xml:space="preserve">
  <value>ResTitleTest</value>
</data>
```

**Usage**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Localized}, Path=[Title]}" />
```

Note: Only after build, the content of `Textblock` will display where in the designer.

[image]

Comment: This has worked for me now, thanks! Should I use the `Binding` approach or the `x:Uid`? I'd rather not use both to not specify everything twice (as this seems like a good source of bugs). Also, I've seen that at runtime the `ResourceLoader` is still being called from the `Binding`, even if the `Text` property is overwritten afterwards by the `x:Uid` mechanism.

Comment: If you want to use resource string at design time, you'd better use the `Binding` approach like the above.

Comment: For me that results in "Item" being displayed rather that the actual value. this is better than no displayed text at all, however since intelliSense does not help with the path property a typo can easily happen and i would like to see that at designTime. Is there a solution for this?